# Draw different graphs at the same position/co-ordinates in python using networkX and matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

Graph 1:

Adjacency list:

2: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

3: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

5: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Plot:

```
`import networkx as nx 
 G = nx.Graph() 
 G1 = nx.Graph() 
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
 for i, j in adj_list.items():
     for k in j:
           G.add_edge(i, k)  
pos = nx.spring_layout(G) 
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_size = 1000, font_size=20)
plt.draw() 
plt.figure() # To plot the next graph in a new figure
plt.show() `
```

[Graph 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYvO7.png)

In graph 2, I am eliminating a few edges and replotting the graph, but the position of nodes is changing, how to store the position of nodes for the next graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-use your `pos` variable while plotting the graph. `nx.spring_layout` returns a dictionary where the node id is the key and the values are the x,y co-ordinates of the node to be plotted. Just reuse the same `pos` variable and pass it as an attribute to `nx.draw` function like this

```
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.Graph() 
G1 = nx.Graph()
adj_list = {2: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],    
3: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],    
5: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
for i, j in adj_list.items():
    for k in j:
        G.add_edge(i, k)  
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)   #<<<<<<<<<< Initialize this only once
nx.draw(G,pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_size = 1000, font_size=20)  #<<<<<<<<< pass the pos variable
plt.draw() 
plt.figure() # To plot the next graph in a new figure
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now I will create a new graph and add only half the edges

```
cnt = 0
G = nx.Graph()
for i, j in adj_list.items():
    for k in j:
        cnt+=1
        if cnt%2 == 0:
            continue
        G.add_edge(i, k)  

nx.draw(G,pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_size = 1000, font_size=20)  #<-- same pos variable is used
plt.draw() 
plt.figure() # To plot the next graph in a new figure
plt.show()
```

[image]
As you can see only half the edges are added and the node positions still remain the same.

Comment: Thank you Mohammed Kashif :)